# automatically update constructor( ), toString( ), hashCode( ) , getters( ) and setters( ) and equals( ) in Intellij when variable in added

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My program had 3 variables

```
private  Integer Patient_id;
private Integer HeartRate;
private Integer RespirationRate;
```

but now I have added a new variable

```
private   Integer timestamp;
```

Is there a provision in IntelliJ to automatically update all the aforementioned methods without deleting them and creating new. Rather than adding or deleting a variable this condition can also occur when type of variable is updated

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but have a quick look at `Project Lombok`. Lombok provides options to autogenerate this things for you by adding a simple annotations to the class. E.g. @Getter for generating the default getter/s.

Comment: I don't think this is possible because IntelliJ can't determine whether a constructor is eligible for modification: what if you want a constructor which doesn't initialise the timestamp field?

Comment: @konsolas: Thanks for this Information. I need to update all the aforementioned methods in my code as another program is using getters and setters to parse data and generate stream which is further sent to Kafka